# Set color of multiple select box option when select box is focused

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to style the `<option>` tag so that there is essentially no style when an option is selected. The reasons for this is that it's a "[duallist box](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/)" so I really don't need the styles.

I've been able to set the background color (white) but when the select menu is focused, it sets the color of the options text to white as well.

I've tried setting the color on the select menu and options. I've tried using pseudo selectors. I've tried inline styles on both the `select` and `option` tags. I can't seem to figure it out. It's obviously possible as that link has the functionality I'm looking for, though similar css doesn't seem to work in my application.

If it helps, I'm styling a custom field in Wordpress admin section as a plugin. Everything is working with the exception of this style.

Also on Chrome currently. Though a cross-browser solution would be best in the end.

Here are some rules I've tried. Along with using classes, id's, and inline styles:

```
table select option,
table select option:hover,
table select option:focus,
table select option:active,
table select option:checked
{
    background: linear-gradient(#fff,#fff); /* works */
    color:red; /* does not work */
}

table select,
table select:focus,
table select:focus option,
table select:focus option:checked
{
    color:red; /* does not work */
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to lie with options that have `selected="selected"` on them. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46st29ae/).

Answer (score -3):

Give an ID ex: opt to your options and try css as below

```
select option#opt {Background.:red;}
```

Comment: No dice. Also, I have the background color working fine. It's the text color.

Comment: Then just give color :red; in above css